# %2B in filenames on plesk server files not showing

Tags: plesk

I am using a plesk server and I seem to have a problem with image files with the %2B character in it. The files are there, for example

```
http://www.perlcoders.net/ebayimages/31KmQN%2BchqL._SL1050_.jpg
```

but its showing a 404 error, I have looked around and can not seem to find a answer for this problem, would it be my default config set up in plesk for the domain that is the problem here, I am running just a standard plesk server with no mods to any confiq files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%2B would get decoded into a + but a + would get decoded as a space. Are you decoding it twice accidentally at all?

Comment: i have simply uploaded the images and when I try to access them directly on my server its giving a 404 error even tho the images are there, I was thinking is is a server config problem

Comment: you are in fact correct it seems they have been accidentally decoded twice, I have download them from the net, then uploaded the files via ftp to my server, in the process they become encoded twice, thank you for pointing this out